# Issue installing express/body-parser node js eclipse plugin

Tags: node.js, eclipse, express, npm

I'm going through the instructions on how to create express web servers through the eclipse/node js plugin in Sam's Teach Yourself All In One book (pg. 26 for reference), and I'm trying to follow them to the best of my ability, but no matter what I do I can't install express, or at least create the sub folders for modules it's asking for.

It's asking me to use 'npm install express@4.6.1' in the console prompt but I get:

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.

I'm like a coding fetus. I don't know what this means. The instructions in the book are asking me to create a folder in the specified path but I'm not really sure how to do that. And in any case, my error message is different from the book's so it could be irrelevant.

I know there's probably some super obvious explanation for this but it's been two hours since I started trying to fix the problem myself, I tried every variation of google search I could think of before coming here, and I'm getting frustrated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you run npm install in uninitialized npm package directory?
you should initialize package with npm init

Comment: I don't really know the difference between an initialized/uninitialized package directory. This is pretty much my first time working with a command prompt.

Comment: An "uninitialized" directory would simply be one that doesn't have a `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a project director. Let's assume you are already in `/Users/user/`. You can check with `pwd`. Then, use `mkdir project` and `cd project` (you should probably give it a better name than `project`).

Next up the errors you are getting are mostly advisory. That is to say they're just warning you that something unexpected is happening but they won't prevent you from making progress on your project. They are letting you know that your directory has no `package.json` file which means your dependency list can't be saved by `npm install`.

You can simply add a `package.json` file manually or use `npm init` to have a boilerplate one created for you. This will also prompt you for information such as the description and license. You are getting warnings about those being missing as well, but of course they are missing since you don't have `package.json`. You don't *need* these -- particularly if you never plan to release this project anywhere. It's just letting you know.

The important thing is to make sure that `node_modules/express` exists relative to your project code.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, I'm just still kind of new to the terminology. Is a project directory just a new project or is it something different entirely? If the important thing is node_modules/express needs to exist, I'm still probably doing something wrong because it's still telling me it doesn't. I should probably go get a book more suited to my knowledge level.